# Problem Handling errors with Application.vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that looks up values across sheets and sums the values. It works so long as the value it is looking up exists across all sheets. If the value does not exist, I'd just like to set the result value to 0.

```vb
Sub lookupSum3()
Dim myVlookupResult As Double
Dim myTableArray As Range
Dim myVlookupSum As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim rowCount As Integer


Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
sheetCount = Sheets.count
rowCount = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Rows.count

i = 2
j = 2

Do While j <= rowCount
Do While i <= sheetCount
Set ws = Sheets(i)
Set myTableArray = ws.Range("A:N")

myVlookupResult = Application.vlookup(ws1.Range("A" & j), myTableArray, 5, False)

If IsError(myVlookupResult) = True Then
    myVlookupResult = 0
End If

myVlookupSum = myVlookupSum + myVlookupResult
i = i + 1
Loop
i = 2
ws1.Range("B" & j) = myVlookupSum
myVlookupSum = 0
j = j + 1
Loop


MsgBox rowCount

End Sub
```

The code will show a run-time error '13' for the line `myVlookupResult = Application.vlookup(ws1.Range("A" & j), myTableArray, 5, False)`

Am I handling the error incorrectly?

Comment: `Dim myVlookupResult As Double`change this to `Dim myVlookupResult As Variant` a `Double` variable can't handle errors if no match is found, a `Variant`Variable will return you `Error2042`or something like that, you can handle it with `If IsError(myVlookupResult) Then`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that worked flawlessly.